# Python: How to define a map of pointers to method inside a class, outside a method

Tags: python-3.x, methods, function-pointers

I want to use some method of a class, especified by a parameter. So I have defined a map of pointers with a diccionary. The problem is that Python doesn't let me define it outside another method (for example the constructor). So I wonder if it is posible. Let me show you an example:

```
class clase():
    mapa = { 1 : metodo1,
             2 : metodo2  }
    def metodo(self,x):
        self.mapa[x]()
    def metodo1(self):
        print("Metodo 1 ejecutado")
    def metodo2(self):
        print("Metodo 2 ejecutado")

objeto = clase()

objeto.metodo(2)
objeto.metodo(1)
```

Here the error says that "name 'metodo1' is not defined"; and If I use this other declaration:

```
class clase():
    mapa = { 1 : self.metodo1,
             2 : self.metodo2  }
...
```

The error is "name 'self' is not defined" (and that surprised me so much!)

How I said, I could do it defining the map inside the constructor. It works. But I want to know if there is any way to do it outside any method because I think I would be more readable during the maintainnig of the code.

ACTUALIZATION:

I proved declaring the map at the end:

```
class clase():

    def metodo(self,x):
        self.mapa[x]()
    def metodo1(self):
        print("Metodo 1 ejecutado")
    def metodo2(self):
        print("Metodo 2 ejecutado")
    mapa = { 1 : metodo1,
             2 : metodo2  }

objeto = clase()
objeto.metodo(2)
```

But I got another error: "metodo2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Comment: The first approach is correct, but you must define the dict *after* the methods.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks, but that generates another kind of error. Please check the actualization.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Python doesn't have explicit pointers because in Python everything is a pointer (ando so, you can use any variable like that, just as in my example).

Comment: @AliRojas no, *python doesn't have pointers*. If you mean that assignment and such has *reference semantics* that's true. In the *CPython, the implementation*, this often involves pointers. But *Python the language doesn't have pointers*. If so, show me how to dereference a pointer, or how to use pointer arithmetic. (So, actually, you *can* use ctypes for this sort of thing, in that sense, there are pointers in `ctypes` but we can ignore a foreign function interface for the purposes of this dicussion)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, they are no pointers seen from the coders eyes, and that's is just an inexact idea mine (an inexact idea that works) because I'm not an expert about programming nomenclature. In my example, I thought that I'm dereferencing a function/method pointer obteined from a diccionary, but how you show me that it's wrong, I would like to know what kind of variables are the values of the "mapa" dictionary... are they just methods? (Please notice that if you declare "mapa" inside a constructor, it works pretty good!)

Comment: `metodo1` is just referencing the function object, which you put inside a dictionary that you assigned to another variable, `mapa`. A method is just a function object that exists in the namespace of a class, which when accessed by an instance of that class, will *automatically* (through the descriptor protocol) get passed the instance to the first positional argument of the function. When you have some object, `obj` and you reference a method on that object, `obj.some_method`, that actually creates *a bound method object*, which is basically a partially applied version of `method`

Comment: Since `self.mapa[x]()` simply retrieves the function object, and it isn't being called on an instance, it doesn't automatically get passed an instance as the first argument, so you would have to do that "manually", e.g. `self.mapa[x](self)`. given a `class Foo: ...`, and `foo = Foo()`, you can think of `foo.some_method()` as equivalent to `Foo.some_method(foo)`. Although ti doesn't work exactly like that, if you want to understand how it actually works, read about [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), function objects are descriptors!